# how to save the custom time in order comment history in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento-2.0.7

```
$orderId = $orderId;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_NEW, true);
$order->setStatus("awaiting_stock");
$order->setUpdate_at(date('2017-03-20 10:14:23', time() - 60*60*24));
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Awaiting Stock');
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

For me

Its not good to use the object manager. Instead you can use the `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository` to load the order You can use the get($entityId) method .
And then you can try `$order->addCommentToStatusHistory($comment, $status = false, $isVisibleOnFront = false); $order->save()` .

Note `addStatusToHistory` `addStatusHistoryComment` are deprecated

Hope this will help

Raviraj